# Intermittent Freezing

Tags: 18.04

Over the last month or so my computer has been freezing for a few seconds at a time, multiple times an hour when I am using my computer. I am running 18.04. I am not sure what outputs would be beneficial to trouble shooting, so I will post outputs if you ask. Thanks for any assistance!

Edit: Output of `sudo parted -l && grep Swap /proc/meminfo`

```
Model: ATA INTEL SSDSCKKF25 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   256GB  256GB  ext4


SwapCached:          324 kB
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
SwapFree:        2091516 kB
```

Comment: @K7AAY all set, not sure if I see anything out of the ordinary with that.

Comment: TY for confirming a 2 GB swap file is set up. Were there any changes made shortly before it started misbehaving?